# Nearest wins maven strategy overriden by scope? How exactly scope is figure out by maven?

Tags: maven

Until today I was certain that maven is using nearest dependency wins strategy, but now I am not sure.

My project contains those two following dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
           <groupId>TestA</groupId>
           <artifactId>TestA</artifactId>
           <version>1.0</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>TestB</groupId>
           <artifactId>TestB</artifactId>
           <version>1.0</version>
       </dependency>
```

Both `A` and `B` have in their poms dependency `C` with scope `compile`

So if someone ask me what version and scope of `C` i would get in my application first answer I come up with is that dependency `C` is get throught `TestA` and will have `test` scope because both are on the same depth and `TestA` is defined first in pom. But that's wrong. In the end my application will contain `C` from `TestB` with scope `compile`. I didn't find anything about how scopes are mediatiated. Why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

None of the dependencies with test scope are included during the compilation and package phases of a Maven build. Since TestB depends on TestC for compilation, TestC gets added as a transitive dependency to your project.

Comment: It is not true, even if i have provided instead of test, then maven is updating provided to compile. It seems like mave always choose the greatest scope.